# Any why to hide or encrypt the url using PHP

Tags: php

I am using below code for opening a window and then capture photo from that window but my code is showing the complete url in address bar which is a security hole. How can I handle this issue kindly give some suggestion / guidance.
Code Java Script in **newenquiry.tpl.php** file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function popup_letter(url) {
         var width  = 700;
         var height = 450;
         var left   = (screen.width  - width)/2;
         var top    = (screen.height - height)/2;
         var params = 'width='+width+', height='+height;
         params += ', top='+top+', left='+left;
         params += ', directories=no';
         params += ', location=no';
         params += ', menubar=no';
         params += ', resizable=no';
         params += ', scrollbars=no';
         params += ', status=no';
         params += ', toolbar=no';
         newwin=window.open(url,'windowname5', params);
         if (window.focus) {
             newwin.focus()
         }
     return false;
}
```

Code to activate the above JS in **same file newenquiry.tpl.php**

```
<td>Take Instant Photo<!--<a href="capture.php" target="blank"><img src="images/capture35.png" title="Capture Image"></a> ?pid=117&action=print_bonafiedcertificate&id  -->

    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="popup_letter('?pid=8&action=print_bonafiedcertificate')" ><img src="images/capture35.png" name="capture" title="Capture Image" border="0" alt="Capture Photo" /></a>

    </td>
```

This code is in **newenquiry.inc.php** where I am calling the file which contain the code for capturing image -

```
if($action=='print_bonafiedcertificate'){
    header("Location:capture.php");
    exit();
//echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL=capture.php">';
//include_once('capture.php');  
}
else{
$es_enquiry = new es_enquiry();
if($Submit == 'Submit')
{
  $vlc    = new FormValidation();   
  if (empty($_POST['reg_no'])) {
  :
  :
```

Kindly give some way to solve this issue

Comment: You can't hide the URL from a user. They will always be able to capture the HTTP request and get the URL.

Comment: why is `?pid=8` never used? If all you do is redirect to `capture.php'` blindley than just call it directly.

Comment: @Yani I tried to use ?PID=8 but I I failed to do this. I am not getting point how to use PID in this code '`if($action=='print_bonafiedcertificate'){
    header("Location:capture.php");
    exit();
}' IF you can give some suggestion I will be thankful

Comment: tried `header("Location:capture.php?pid=" . $_GET['pid'])` ?

Comment: @Yani Thank you, it work perfectly what I expected.

Answer (score 0):

There are generally many ways to capture the URL, like some developer tools integrated in browser, Tamper data (a Firefox extension) and many more. You should not rely on it (from security reasons).

If the URL can be used by some users only, you should verify the authentication on this page.

If the URL should be used for example once per a payment, you can use a one-time ticket.

If nothing fits to your situation, specify your needs, please.

Comment: No it is not payment based this for registered user only Well I used authentication of user like this `<?php session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['eschools']['admin_user']) || $_SESSION['eschools']['admin_user']=="" ) {
 header('location: ./?pid=1&unauth=0');
 exit;
}` and this working fine but problem comes when user logged in and use the `http://software.manazeschool.com/office_admin/capture.php` they can access this page directly without coming via proper page.
?>

Comment: Is it really a security problem? Can an user bypass anything this way?